# How to fix low spots in concrete slab

Tags: concrete

I have a couple exterior concrete slabs (walkways and pool deck) and although the slabs are slopped, in some area water is pooling. Looks like there are some low spots, creating 1/16" deep puddles.

Can self leveling cement help fill in the low spots? Would I be able to maintain the overall slope of the slab? Aesthetic consideration aside, would that make the problem worst?

Comment: It's not really for heavy loads, so do you park there? In terms of slope, it will be somewhere between ideal and how it is now.

Comment: no parking, just foot traffic

Comment: In my opinion this is one of those things where the attempted fix will cause you a whole new sept of problems, probably worse. Anything "self leveling" is going to attempts to level the slope itself. Any coating that you put on the surface will likely wear away, probably unevenly and look horrible in short order, requiring regular removal and replacement.Ugh... not worth it.

Comment: 1/16" or 1.5mm. Crikey. Remember that concrete is a wet process and I'd be interested to see any concrete you can find in a yard which has better accuracy than 1/16 of an inch over an area...

Comment: I agree with Jraef I have tried self leveling outside , drilling holes about the only fix was grinding the low side but the ground area is quite slippery when wet compared to the brushed areas , I ended up over coating with epoxy pebble the rough surface drains well but expensive.